# error evaluationScheme function in R

Tags: r, prediction, recommendation-engine, evaluation

Now, I'm working on a recommender systems in R. the goal is ratings prediction not recommending.
I got my reshaped matrix where rows are users (#94682), columns are items (#40), entries are ratings. I want to to apply cross validation using "evaluationScheme" function in R as:

```
n_fold <- 10
scheme <- evaluationScheme(data = r, 
                          method = "cross-validation",
                          k = n_fold, 
                          given = 40, 
                          goodRating = 1)
```

I realized that if I put "given = 40" which includes all the items for evaluation, then when I reach the prediction part I get a matrix with size 0! However if I change it to any number between 1 and 39, I got the prediction right. Why is that happening? Note that I'm using task1 data which you can find it here: https://github.com/dalalalsh/Ryerson

Code is attached.